# Where can I get a Notification item layout? Something like android.R.layout.?

Tags: android, layout, notifications

As you can see in Android and OEM customisation, the items in Status Bar or Notification bar have different layouts.

The notification also differs depending on the Theme/Rom you installed.

Here is an example with Vanilla/Touchwizz/MIUI:

[image] or [image] or [image]

What I would like to get is the layout, so I can include it in my activity and preview a notification inside my application.

I guess there is something similar to the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 for listview for instance.

Thank a lot for any help or any clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout for notification is located in separate `SystemUI` package: [status_bar_latest_event](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/res/layout/status_bar_latest_event.xml&q=status_bar_latest_event&exact_package=android&type=cs) (as of Android 2.3). This is not directly accessible from application. And if you could extract the layout, it wouldn't help you, as it uses custom `com.android.systemui.statusbar.LatestItemView` view. So you'd need to load that class into your process using `PathClassLoader`.

So theoretically this might be possible, but it's going to be tricky.

Comment: I am so sad that no solution exist, but as this seem to be correct, I accept!